# how to install Nepali font such that the terminal can display it

Tags: command-line, unicode

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGAJf.png) I am working on the terminal such that I can read the output but for some reason I am not able to display unicode / nepali characters in the terminal properly
For example I want to display this in the terminal

```
विश्व क्रिकेट लिग च्याम्पियनसिपमा नेदरल्यान्ड्सविरुद्व नेपाल सजिलै सात विकेटले पराजित भयो । शनिबार नेदरल्यान्ड्ससँग नेपाल ९४ रनमै अलआउट भयो । लिस्ट ए मान्यता प्राप्त खेलमा नेपालको यो सबैभन्दा न्युन स्कोर हो
```

but the terminal display is not proper, Please check it. I am obtaining the data from this [website](http://www.ekantipur.com/)

Comment: Which Nepali font do you find best ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Konsole** (terminal) & every thing is working now.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. It means the problem is solved.

Comment: as a new user I can accept my answer only after two days . thnx